# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser wrong get text

Tags: php, parsing

I have problem with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. I can't get links and text from the correct div tag...
Here is url, http://apeiron.comyr.com/asd.php, and here is url to want to parse [link](http://www.apeiron-uni.eu/lycboardclient/Default.aspx?DepartmentID=2).

**Here is code:**

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    ini_set('short_open_tag', '0');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.apeiron-uni.eu/lycboardclient/Default.aspx?DepartmentID=2');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo '{ "rezultati":[ ';
    //$i = 1;
foreach($html->find('div[id=center].post') as $article) {
        $item['datum']    = $article->find('div.post-date', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['text'] =     $article->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['more'] = $article->find('a', 0)->href;           
    //  if($i < 11){    

                $datum=$item['datum'];
                $text=$item['text'];
                $link=$item['more'];

                $xml=array("datum" =>$datum ,"text" => $text,"link" => $link);              
                echo json_encode($xml).",";

                /*  
        }
        else{           
        }*/
        //$i++; 
    }

echo ']}'; 
?>
```

Comment: I edited so it would be in perfectly understandable english.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: foreach div[id=center] suggests that the id is being used than once which would be quite rare. Having looked at the Simple HTML Dom parser documentation, have you tried just doing $html->find('div.post') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=center].post') as $article) { ... }
```

should be

```
foreach($html->find('div#center .post') as $article) { ... }
```

**Output:**

> {"Results": [{"date": "Friday, 01.03.2013. Year", "text": "The \
>   u0161tita ra \ u010dunarskih and business systems", "link":
>   "Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 & NewsID = 9429 "}, {" date ":"
>   Wednesday, 27.02.2013. year "," text ":" You \ u0161a Mathematics test
>   2 - full-time and part-time students "," link ":" Detail.aspx? NewsID
>   = 9407 "}, {" date ":" Tuesday, 26.02.2013. year "," text ":" Theory of System II period "," link ":" Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 &
>   NewsID = 8434 "}, {" date "" Monday, 25.02.2013. year "," text ":" You
>   \ u0161a-II math test "," link ":" Detail.aspx? NewsID = 9387 "}, {"
>   date ":" Monday, 25.02 .2013. year "," text ":" Germany \ u010dki
>   Language I "," link ":" Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 & NewsID = 9391
>   "}, {" date ":" Friday, 22.02.2013. was " "text": "STATISTICS-RESULTS
>   preceding duties", "link": "Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 & NewsID =
>   9372"}, {"date": "Friday, 22.02.2013. year", "text": "Theory decision
>   \ u010divanja - prerequisites "," link ":" Default.aspx? DepartmentID
>   = 2 & NewsID = 9366 "}, {" date ":" Wednesday, 20.02.2013. year "," text ":" II the January deadline with Prof. . Mirela Simi \ u0107 ","
>   link ":" Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 & NewsID = 9354 "}, {" date
>   ":" Monday, 18.02.2013. year "," text ":" The theory of decision \
>   u010divanja-test II "," link ":" Default.aspx? DepartmentID = 2 &
>   NewsID = 9310 "}, {" date ":" Monday, 18.02.2013. year "," text ":"
>   Informatics and ra \ u010dunarske technology "," link "" Default.aspx?
>   DepartmentID = 2 & NewsID = 9319 "},]}